# Is there a normed space which is isometric to a proper subspace of itself?

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

Already that the normed vector space here cannot be real number R as every isometry from R will sent to R itself. Cannot be N either as N itself is not a normed vector space at all. Then how can I approach the problem?

Comment: What kind of normed spaces do you know? Do you know for example sequence spaces?

Comment: In fact any such example needs to be infinite dimensional by the Mazur-Ulam Theorem. So take your favourite infinite dimensional normed space :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a normed space is necessarily a vector space. The [Mazur-Ulam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) theorem tells us that for any isometry $f:X \to Y$, the function $g:X \to Y$ defined by $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$ will be a (bijective) *linear* isometry. That is, any two isometric normed spaces will necessarily be isomorphic as vector spaces. Using this fact, we can conclude that if $X$ is a finite-dimensional normed space, then no proper subspace $Y$ of $X$ will be isometric to $X$. In particular, we would necessarily have $\dim(Y) < \dim(X)$, which means that $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic as vector spaces and are therefore not isometric as normed spaces.

So, to get a suitable example, we need an infinite dimensional normed space. Probably the most intuition-friendly of these spaces is the [sequence space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#%E2%84%93p_spaces) $\ell^2$. In particular, the elements of $\ell^2$ are sequences $x = (x_i)_{i \in \Bbb N} = (x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$. More specifically, we have
$$
\ell^2 = \left\{(x_i)_{i \in \Bbb N} : \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2 < \infty\right\}.
$$
We define a norm on this set by $\|x\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2}.$ You might find it a useful exercise to show that $\ell^2$ satisfies the definition of a normed space.

With that established, consider the space $X = \ell^2$ and its subspace $Y$ defined by
$$
Y = \{(x_i)_{i \in \Bbb N} \in X : x_1 = 0\}.
$$
Verify that $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and that there is indeed an isometry between these two spaces.

Comment: will it be easier to just define a inner product on l^(2)? As the triangle inequality for the norm will need this inner product to be proved.

Comment: @Marcel Indeed this norm corresponds to an inner product. To rigorously do things this way, you must show that a certain inner product is in fact an inner product and show that this inner product induces the norm I’ve defined (and then note that the “norm” induced by an inner product is in fact a norm)